# Refresh Token does not work in Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

---

So I define all parameters on the top of my page:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

     $client->getAccessToken();



} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


//get the access token
 $myToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());


if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

    $token = $myToken->refresh_token;
    echo 'token expired';


} else {

    $token = $myToken->access_token;
    echo 'token not yet expired'; 

}

    ?>
```

Down at the bottom I got java script:

```
<script>


gapi.analytics.ready(function() {


 var CLIENT_ID = 'my-client-id-goes-here';

   gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
   'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '<?php echo $token; ?>'
    }
  });
```

This works however until access token expires, which is in 60 minutes. After that reports are not showing anymore. What did I do wrong and why it doesn't use a refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the expected behavior (unfortunately). The Embed API does not take a refresh token because generally you never want to expose those tokens publicly (which you would be doing if they were in your HTML source).

If you wanted to work around this limitation, you could set a timer on the page that updated the access token every 50 minutes or so (they expire after 60, as you pointed out).

If you had an endpoint on your server that returned a new access token, you could do something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  makeRequestToGetNewAccessToken().then(function(access_token) {
    gapi.auth.setToken({
      access_token: access_token
    });
  });
}, 1000 * 60 * 50);
```

Note, the key above is calling [`setToken`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsettokentoken) with the new access token. That will allow the Embed API to continue to work as normal.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me. What should I put instead "access_token" i here:? gapi.auth.setToken({
      access_token: "what should be here" ?
    });

Also as an alternative solution is there anyway to set token expiration to be sometime in for example 30 years..?

Comment: It's the same thing you have above in your code: `'<?php echo $token; ?>'`. Also, to answer your second question, no you can't change the expires period. It's set to 1 hour for security reasons.

Comment: ok, that didn't work..I've put your code above this line: gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
   'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '<?php echo $token; ?>'
    } and waited for an hour, it didn't seem to set new token.

Comment: It definitely works. You can verify that it sets the token by calling `gapi.auth.getToken()`, and it will return the token you just set.

Comment: alert(gapi.auth.getToken()); returned null

Comment: That means you never called `gapi.auth.setToken()`. Please check your code to make sure.

Comment: so the reason it's not set is because it errors out on  "makeRequestToGetNewAccessToken is undefined" in that piece of code you provided. I was hoping this work around would work..

Comment: Yes, that was a function I was implying that you'd have to implement. It would make a request to your server and return a promise that's resolved with an access token.